# VSCode override semantic highlight with syntax highlight, for specific token types

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, highlight

### Description

When a language extension marks `class` or `void` as `keyword` in [semantic highlight](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/semantic-highlight-guide#semantic-token-classification), I cannot use syntax highlight rule to give them specific colours. For example, in this image, `class` `static` `void` `string` are all highlighted as `keyword`, but I want to highlight them differently.

In the same time, I **do not** want to turn off semantic highlight **entirely**, like, for line 5 in the picture, it colours the tokens correctly.

[Example Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaD9h.png)

I want to find a way that can **occationally** turn off the semantic highlight, and use syntax highlight rules instead.

### What I have tried

I have tried the *Alternate Solution: Use Semantic Tokens Intermittently* at the bottom of this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71857132/20445940), but it is still overrided by semantic highlight.

I add this rule like this, still the textmate scope is overrided while the semantic token has a rule for `keyword` (this **only works** when `keyword` is missing in `semanticTokenColors`, but that will loss the advantage of semantic highlight: all in all, I cannot predict that which token will be *wrongly parsed* for all language possible, so I cannot just simply leave `semanticTokenColors` empty):

[Test Result Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESUam.png)